# Puzzle #5: As Hard as ABC

Tags: lateral-thinking

A piece of paper was found in a kindergarten classroom trash can. On the paper there is a list of letters. It is pretty obvious what the task was when you notice what the paper says.

A B C D _

It's pretty obvious that the letter "E" is next. Can you finish this task?

Oh, and one more thing, you need to show the letter "E" next to the "D" *without writing* the letter "E".

Comment: Well, I'm back now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write

> the letter F in the blank, which combined with the underline makes an E.

Comment: Correct, good job